# NLTK: bar chart for frequency of modals

Tags: python, nltk

I am a nltk beginner. Recently, I am facing difficulties when drawing a bar chart for frequency of modals.

```
colors = 'rgbcmyk'
def bar_chart(categories, words, counts):
    import pylab
    ind = pylab.arange(len(words))
    width = 1 / (len(categories) + 1)
    bar_groups = []
    for c in range(len(categories)):
        bars = pylab.bar(ind+c*width, counts[categories[c]], width, 
                         color=colors[c % len(colors)])
        bar_groups.append(bars)
    pylab.xticks(ind+width, words)
    pylab.legend([b[0] for b in bar_groups], categories, loc = 'upper left')
    pylab.ylabel('Frequency')
    pylab.title('Frequency of Six Modal Verbs by Genre')
    pylab.show()

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
genres = ['news', 'religion', 'hobbies', 'government', 'adventure']
modals = ['can', 'could', 'may', 'might', 'must', 'will']
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
        (genre, word)
        for genre in brown.categories()
        for word in brown.words(categories = genre)
        if word in modals)
counts = {}
for genre in genres:
    counts[genre] = [cfd[genre][word] for word in modals]
bar_chart(genre, modals, counts)
```

The format could be provided by Python after running the function 'bar_chart,' but the bar could not be seen. I suspected whether Python did not read the data from brown, so I used:

```
cfd.tabulate(conditions = genres, samples = modals)
```

Output:

> ```
>              can could   may might  must  will 
>       news    93    86    66    38    50   389 
>   religion    82    59    78    12    54    71 
>    hobbies   268    58   131    22    83   264 
> government   117    38   153    13   102   244 
>  adventure    46   151     5    58    27    50
> ```

It seems that Python read the data. I want to ensure where the mistakes are. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I always hate dealing with bar charts and try to extract as much of the effort away as possible. One way to do this is by using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to load your data as a DataFrame and then use its plotting interface (which uses matplotlib) to create the bar chart.

So you could get rid of the `bar_chart` function and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(counts.values()), counts.keys(), modals)
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

That being said the trouble with showing the image is really dependent upon what environment you are working in. If you are in Jupyter you can use the magic command `%matplotlib inline` and the image will pop up right after calling the plot method. If you are writing a script and want to save the image you can do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('some file name.png')
```

You should end up with something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are trying to run it from cmdline or some IDE. In the latter case displaying the chart may be blocked by IDE. Try command line.

Comment: Yes, and I solved this difficulties. Thank you so much.